# Events Organiser Wordpress only show if

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show "Stay Tuned..." if there are no Upcoming Events.

Sure there is a simple solution here, I've just never worked with the combination of PHP and shortcodes before.

For reference: http://docs.wp-event-organiser.com/shortcodes/events-list/

## Upcoming Events

[eo_events event_start_after=today showpastevents=false] %event_title% on %start{jS M Y}{ g:i:a}% [/eo_events]

## Past Events

[eo_events event_end_before=today] %event_title% on %start{jS M Y}{ g:i:a}% [/eo_events]

Comment: what format you are showing calendar or document format of event listing. either check any settings are there for no upcoming events , if not either check the code of plugin or do some jquery stuff and will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the `showpastevents` parameter will be deprecated some time soon, so might be good to leave it out.

There are a few ways to achieve this. Here's some raw code that will achieve the desired results (using the shortcode; of course you could do the same thing just using functions):

```
// GET FUTURE ------------------
if (function_exists("eo_get_events")) {
    $events = eo_get_events(array(
        'event_start_after'=>'today',
    ));

    if ($events) { 
       echo do_shortcode("[eo_events event_start_after=\"today\"]%event_title% on %start{jS M Y}{ g:i:a}% [/eo_events]");
    } else {
       echo "Stay Tuned....";
    }
}

// GET PAST ------------------
if (function_exists("eo_get_events")) {
    $events = eo_get_events(array(
         'event_end_before'=>'today'
    ));

    if ($events) { 
       echo do_shortcode("[eo_events event_end_before=\"today\"]%event_title% on %start{jS M Y}{ g:i:a}% [/eo_events]");
    } else {
       echo "No Past Events....";
    }
}
```